# dnf-automatic hangs on an irrelevant RPM post-install script - can I set a timeout or kill it automatically?

Tags: systemd, rpm, udev, background-process, dnf

I have noticed that on a server a nightly `dnf-automatic` script for automatic system updates has been running for a few weeks instead of exiting after a few minutes. It hangs on these commands:

```
# ps auxfww
USER         PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ    RSS TTY     STAT START   TIME COMMAND
(...)
root      348542  0.0  0.1 659696 130952 ?       Ss   Sep24   0:05 /usr/libexec/platform-python /usr/bin/dnf-automatic /etc/dnf/automatic.conf --timer --installupdates
root      348642  0.0  0.0  14848   3168 ?        S   Sep24   0:00  \_ /bin/sh /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.UowQaa 2
root      348643  0.0  0.0  94600   9408 ?        S   Sep24   0:00      \_ udevadm trigger --sysname-match=hw_random --settle
```

Where does it come from?  Apparently an RPM post-install script, I suppose:

```
# cat /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.UowQaa
if [ $1 -eq 1 ] ; then 
        # Initial installation 
        systemctl --no-reload preset rngd.service rngd-wake-threshold.service &>/dev/null || : 
fi

udevadm trigger --sysname-match=hw_random --settle
```

`udevadm` hangs for several days or weeks. It should not be called in the first place. I do not need any `udev` thing since this is a server, and no such daemon is running.

**Question:** May I avoid calling, or detect and kill such nonsense processes easily and automatically?

Of course I could `cp -p /usr/bin/true /usr/sbin/udevadm` but I would rather not tamper with system binaries.

Also, some RPM post install scripts are useful (e.g. restart web/mail server process after updating it) so disabling all RPM post-install scripts is not an option.

Comment: This bug report looks similar to your issue https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1975588 what is the distribution used ? Could it be that the fix hasn't reach your version maybe ? It seems to come from the package called `rng-tools`, not sure if it's possible to specify to skip the post-install script for a specific package.

Comment: @Pierre-AlainTORET Thanks for finding that. Too bad the fix won't help me. Perhaps we can find a different solution?